# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE & ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am creating a web-crawler using webdriver that is supposed to search some information for companies in a website, but while it`s crawling i get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and sometimes ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Mannually i must to reload the website till the search is completed

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried, so someone here can debug. If possible, please post the website link too

Comment: without code it's hard to tell. But maybe the server-side detects that your spams the site with requests and blacklists your requests